# Android resources in Eclipse and in Ant build

Tags: android, ant

If I try to build my project in Eclipse it works without any problems, but if I build it with Ant, I see errors like:

```
[javac] /mnt/sda1/development/workspaces/ws_arealpilot/ArealPilot/src/com/example/myapp/MyActivity.java:29: cannot find symbol
[javac] symbol  : variable mylayout
[javac] location: class com.example.myapp.R.id
[javac]         myLayout = (View) findViewById(com.example.myapp.R.id.mylayout);
```

And indeed the R class generated by Ant doesn't contain some ids and strings, but they are included if I build the project with Eclipse.

I suppose some resources are "wrong" or something like this. So my question is how can I find out which resources make problems?

Answer (score 0):

Well there's something wrong with your project setup.

You activity package seems to be com.example while the R package is com.example.myapp

Comment: I don't think so. The package name of the activity can be freely choosen. But in my post it was an "example" name :) So I made an edit on my post.

Comment: Have you created the project with ant or with eclipse? According to this, eclipse won't generate all the necessary files for ant to build correctly http://incise.org/android-development-on-the-command-line.html

Comment: Thank you very much for the link. I'll check it. I've created the project a couple of months ago in eclipse, but it was compilable with Ant too. I don't know which changes are the cause of compilation errors now. May be it is the last ADT update may be something other...

Comment: Yeah sounds like you might have to run "android update project" Good luck!

Comment: Thank you, Robert... But I had no luck :( "android update project" didn't help.

Comment: Does 'ant clean release' compiles the project? Have you try 'ant clean install release'? On the other hand you can try to create an empty project from the command line using http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-cmdline.html#CreatingAProject and once you verify it builds fine, you copy your source code/resources inside the new project

Comment: I have tried "ant clean release". But the project cannot be compiled (because of the problems with R). Yes, you are right, the last possibility is to try to create a new project :)